# Tableau Desktop : Generate an incremental field based on a string field (for a Path/Destination Map)

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to generate a "Destination Map" in Tableau.

I have ticketing info under a text field called "PNR" in my DB which is the passenger name record. It is a serial of numbers and letters 6 to 9 positions unique per travel.

Behind each PNR, there is a serial of tickets numbers which has been transformed in a new field to a sequence of numbers from 1 to x to have the order of the flights for the Map later.

Now I need to group each PNR to a sequence of numbers. In other words :

[Index Formula I used but I do not understand the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16BJM.png) :
Index() along the PNR field

[Result of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x20Jw.png) :
All the green boxes are for me correct results of the formula
All the red boxes are for me a none correct results for this formula
What I do not understand is why from the ninth group the numbers do not follow.

Is it the right choice of formula ? Method ?
Thanks in advance for all your support !

Comment: How is 'PNR' being sorted here? If there is a calculation behind PNR, the sorting of index (i.e. row in the partition) may not be as you expect.
If you remove everything but PNR and the ID Group, how does it look?

Comment: "PNR" is sorted ascending. PNR is not a calculated field it is a text field. If I remove all fields except PNR and ID Group it looks like it works. But I need to have this "index" number for every row with the same PNR. The goal is to have a numerical column from 1 to x, and then with my other field for each flight I will be able to draw my map like this : https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_howto_origin_destination.htm#example-1-metro-station-traffic-in-paris-france